# Display the line breaks in user bio without using html

Tags: users, user-meta, sanitization, wp-user-query

User fills their user bio using Formidable forms.

It saves correctly and displays with line breaks in Worpdress admin on the user overview page.

It displays without line breaks on the site.

The only solution I found is to disable HTML sanitization and manually edit each profile and add `<p>` or `<br>` tags which is not an ideal solution. This is not ideal as it enables all HTML plus the need for manual edits of each profile.

What I would like is to display the line breaks as they were originally entered and saved in Wordpress. This would allow a simple workflow for users to add and update their profile without using HTML code.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you currently displaying the bio on the site?

Comment: @JacobPeattie in 2 ways: Elementor author profile widget and the theme author bio box. Also happy to use Advanced Custom Fields if that would make it easier.

Answer (score 1):

You could use "white-space: pre;" in CSS to display newlines as they are

Answer (score 0):

You can use the nl2br PHP function.
It means insert line breaks where newlines (\n) occur in the string.
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_nl2br.asp

example:

```
echo nl2br($userbio);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But then you're printing the rest of the string unescaped, including any HTML tags entered, as OP said they were worried about.